# swift 5 Помогите, пожалуйста, создать массив из 5 кнопок

Tags: swift, xcode

Вся информация, что я находил, либо не работает, либо не подходит. И как обратиться к отдельному элементу массива?

```
var ButMass : [UIButton] = Array()
```

Весь код:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @objc func Trans(ButCol:UIButton, sender: UIButton) {
        for But in ButMass {
            But.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    var ButCol2 = UIButton()
    var ButCol3 = UIButton()
    var ButCol4 = UIButton()
    var ButCol5 = UIButton()
    var ButMassStart : [UIButton] = Array(
    var ButMass : [UIButton] = Array()
    
    var NamesForCol : [String] = ["fruits", "city", "clock"]
    var CountNamesWords : [Int] = [4, 4, 3]
    var DictCol : Dictionary = ["":""]
    var DictCol1 : Dictionary = ["Apple":"Яблоко", "Pear":"Груша", "Garnet":"Гранат", "Grape":"Виноград", "House":"Дом", "Market":"Рынок", "Shop":"магазин", "Place":"Площадь", "Two":"Два", "Arrow":"Стрелка", "Eleven":"Одиннадцать", "Ten":"Десять"]
    var ButWord = UIButton()
    var DoubleButCheck : Bool = true
    var heightOfTop = 50
    var ButColSize : Int = Int(round(UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 30))
    var ButColPlace2 : Int = Int(round(UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 + 10))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
        var labelEnd = UILabel()
        labelEnd.text = "Words is ending. Please, waiting new words"
        labelEnd.center = self.view.center
        while NamesForCol.isEmpty == false {
            ButMass.append(ButMassStart[0])
            ButMassStart[0].delete()
        }
        if NamesForCol.isEmpty != true {
            labelEnd.isHidden = true
            for ButCol in ButMass {
                ButSet(ButCol: ButCol)
            }
        } else {
            labelEnd.isHidden = false
        }
        ButWord.frame.size = CGSize(width: 260, height: 260)
        ButWord.center = self.view.center
        ButWord.isHidden = true

    
    }
    func ButSet(ButCol:UIButton) {
        var ButColFrame = CGRect(x: 20, y: heightOfTop, width: ButColSize, height: ButColSize)
        var ButColFrame2 = CGRect(x: ButColPlace2, y: heightOfTop, width: ButColSize, height: ButColSize)
        if DoubleButCheck {
            ButCol.frame = ButColFrame
            ButCol.backgroundColor = .green
            ButCol.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
            ButCol.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Trans), for: .touchDown)
            self.view.addSubview(ButCol)
            DoubleButCheck = false
        } else {
            ButCol.frame = ButColFrame2
            ButCol.backgroundColor = .green
            ButCol.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
            self.view.addSubview(ButCol)
            DoubleButCheck = true
            heightOfTop = heightOfTop + ButColSize + 50
        }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне даже интересно стало как вы ищете. А как вы пробовали? Может все-таки добавите чуть больше кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот минимальный пример на основе вашего кода - кнопки создаются в цикле.

Несколько замечаний касательно стиля программирования в Swift, которые у вас не соблюдены, что затрудняет чтение кода ([руководство по стилю](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide))

- имена переменных пишутся с маленькой буквы
- не нужно сокращать названия переменных и методов, пишите полностью, чтобы не приходилось гадать, что эти названия означают
- разделяйте логические блоки кода пустыми строками

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let buttonsColumnSize = Int(round(UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 30))
    
    var buttons = [UIButton]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createButtons()
        // access array mambers
        buttons[1].setTitle("other title", for: .normal)
    }
    
    private func createButtons() {
        
        var y = 50
        
        for i in 0..<5 {
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: y, width: buttonsColumnSize, height: buttonsColumnSize)
            button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
            button.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: .normal)
            // other setup ...
            view.addSubview(button)
            buttons.append(button)
            
            y += buttonsColumnSize + 50
        }
    }

}
```